# How to reverse map of objects to vector of tuples by using an iterator?

Tags: rust

What is the easiest way to convert `HashMap<String, String>` to `Vec<(String, Vec<String>)>` by using an iterator ? I want to reverse the map.

I've tried to use `iter()` methods but have no idea how to do a correct `map` closure implementation for collecting values after:

```
fn get_aliases(&self) -> Vec<(String, Vec<String>)> {
    let mut aliases: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    aliases.insert("a".to_owned(), "test".to_owned());
    aliases.insert("b".to_owned(), "test".to_owned());
    aliases.insert("c".to_owned(), "test2".to_owned());

    aliases.iter().map(|(ref a, ref c)| {
        // what to do here?
    }).collect()

    // the expected return value is:
    // [("test", ["a", "b"]), ("test2", ["c"])]
}
```

This function will return a vector which says what `String` keys belong to some object.

I could write a lot of code with `for` and `find`s but it seems to me this would be less efficient and I think there is a way to do that by using iterators only.

Comment: Is `Object` hashable or `Ord`?  I think I'd collect into a map (`HashMap` or `BTreeMap`) with key/value swapped first to merge the keys, and then flatten that into a `Vec`.

Comment: A simple example showing (1) the content of `aliases` and (2) the expected content of the resulting `Vec` would go a long way to making this question slightly more understandable.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have simplified the question a lot and I hope it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I could write a lot of code with `for` and `find`s but it seems to me this would be less efficient and I think there is a way to do that by using iterators only.

I wouldn't call it *a lot* of code, and remember that `for` loops **operate on iterators**. I've not done any benchmarking, but this is far simpler and I'd expect it to be more performant:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_aliases(aliases: HashMap<String, String>) -> Vec<(String, Vec<String>)> {
    let mut x = HashMap::new();

    for (k, v) in aliases {
        x.entry(v).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(k)
    }

    x.into_iter().collect()
}

fn main() {
    let mut aliases = HashMap::new();
    aliases.insert("a".to_owned(), "test".to_owned());
    aliases.insert("b".to_owned(), "test".to_owned());
    aliases.insert("c".to_owned(), "test2".to_owned());

    println!("{:?}", get_aliases(aliases));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not trivial, certainly not as trivial as it would be with some other stream libraries that provide the necessary functions.

You can use the itertools crate's `group_by` to group elements by some key. However, it only groups adjacent elements, so you have to sort them first. Here's my result:

```
impl A {
    pub fn get_aliases(&self) -> Vec<(String, Vec<String>)> {
        // Get a Vec of string references for sorting. Reverse element
        // order for clarity.
        let mut v = self.aliases.iter()
            .map(|(a, c)| (&c[..], &a[..])).collect::<Vec<_>>();
        v.sort_by_key(|t| t.0); // Make identical keys adjacent.
        let g = v.into_iter().group_by(|t| t.0); // Create grouping.
        g.into_iter()
            .map(|(key, group)| // key is the str with the key
                                // group is a subiterator that just visits
                                // elements with that key, Item=&(&str,&str)
                (key.to_string(), // result is a tuple of the key as String
                 group.map(|t| t.1.to_string()).collect())
                   // and the subiterator turned into a Vec<String>
                )
            .collect() // finally, turn Iterator<Item=(String, Vec<String>) into Vec
    }
}
```

Going back to your original problem, you have the additional issue that `Arc<Object>` is only `PartialEq` (needed by `group_by`) if `Object` is; same for `Ord` (needed by `sort_by_key`). If your `Object` type cannot be compared that way and you want to use the pointer identity, your intermediate vector will need to store some newtype wrapper around `Arc` that uses pointer values for comparison.